# Install trigger on script created from Google WebApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am creating WebApp in **Google Apps Script** that creates script file in user Google drive.

Now I need to install time trigger on that script. How can I do that?

Official documentation allows me install triggers only if I call script from project where I want to install triggers. Maybe I can call that script not from my **WebApp** scope but from that newly created project scope?

Comment: the only supported way is to use addons.

Comment: So I should tell user to install trigger manually? :/

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to achieve this (other than publishing an add-on)

1. put the script embedded on a spreadsheet. add code on onOpen that adds a "configure" menu with an item that will create the trigger if not there yet.
2. make a copy of the sheet. have the user open the sheet and execute the menu item.

this is much easier (for the user) than having her dive into the script editor.